# Problems while sorting alphabeticaly a .txt file (one line was dropped)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, io

I need to sort alphabetically a .txt file that contains an id and a content column like this:

```
SSADDS__234_234dvefeSADF, 1
SSFDS2342_234_dfsk___wewrew, 2
....
DFGFG__sasd_DFSD23423_3232, 3
```

Then I do the following to sort it:

```
f=open(raw_input("give me the file"))
for word in f:
    l = sorted(map(str.strip, f))
    #print "\n",l
    a = open(r'path', 'w')
    #a.writelines(l)
    a.write('\n'.join(l)+'\n')
```

The file contain 500 lines (id and content). The problem with this is that when I run the above script I get 499 instead of 500, why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you sorting inside the for loop? Also, do you get index 499, ex. f[499] or do you get length 499, len(f) == 499?

Comment: Because this was the best way I figure out of doing this... any oder idea of how to sort alfabeticaly this?. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just eliminate `for` loop and you'll be good to go:

```
from string import strip

with open(raw_input("give me the file")) as f:
    lines = sorted(map(strip, f))

    with open(r'path', 'w') as a:
        a.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in for loop. just remove for loop and run your program without any other changes.